# My terminal applications start bash, but no init files are getting sourced

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, iterm

This problem suddenly appeared out of nowhere and shows in both Terminal and iTerm2.

When I start the apps, usually they would run my selected shell, whose path is configured as `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`. This shell would then source `.bashrc`, `.profile` and `.bash_profile`. Now all of a sudden, none of these files are getting sourced, causing all sorts of havoc.

For instance, a fresh iTerm instance shows

```
echo $SHELL
/opt/homebrew/bin/bash
```

But none of my init files are sourced. Now if I manually run `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`, everything gets sourced. Same if I just run plain `bash` from `/bin/bash`.

The app is configured to run `/opt/homebrew/bash -l` as a login shell:

[image]

Yet it just doesn't work, and apparently in each tab I have to manually run the shell.

What could this be caused by and what can I do about it? I have run `chsh -s /opt/homebrew/bin/bash` to no avail.

Comment: Where are your init files located?

Comment: home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it turns out `.bash_profile` is getting sourced, so adding `. $HOME/.bashrc` and the like here will make it work again. But I don't really understand why `~/.bashrc` is not getting sourced regardless for interactive shells.

Comment: .bashrc is not run automatically for login shells, you‘ll need to source it specifically.

Comment: @oarfish  Please read the INVOCATION section of the `bash` man page, it details under what conditions `bash` reads its various rc files.

Comment: Because it is documented in this way, in the bash man-page: _When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists._ Don't ask me why the designers of bash decided it in this way.